SELECT INTO Statement fails with arithmetic overflow but SELECT Statement runs without errors
Currently I have a strange problem and I need clarification (for my mind).
Problem description:
Today I found a stored procedure which runs two statements.
First it drops a table and later it recreates this table again with a SELECT INTO statement. The stored procedure is part of our BI nightly runs and today throws a exception.
The exception which was thrown was: 8115 Arithmetic overflow while convert numeric to numeric.

Normaly when this kind of error happens we have a value which is to big to fit in a smaller datatyp and we try to cast the value to this datatyp.
For example lets say we have the value 12345,12 and we want to cast this to decimal(6,2).
This wont work and throw this error.
Normaly when this happens I do this SET ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT OFF; and search the result for NULL values to further analyse the values. But this time there are no null values. And the second interessting thing is, if I remove the INTO part of the SELECT INTO statement there is no error.
So this exception only occurs when the statement is executed as SELECT INTO. If the same statement is executed as SELECT the error is gone.

I have tried multible things now to narrow this:

I have tried to change the cast statement to a try_cast statement and this works (also with the SELECT INTO (and with no NULLs in the result) -> So the try_cast does exactly what we want the cast to do. Is there a difference?
I have tried to convert the value to varchar and find the decimal sepperator position of each value to check if there is a value which is bigger than expected (which is not the case). -> The highest number I get was 10 so we have 9 digites to the left of the comma and we use decimal(12,3) here, which should be fine.
I have tried to change the cast from decimal(12,3) to decimal(13,3) which works too but make no sense to me because the maximum decimal seperator is 9.


To fix the problem I now have changed the cast to a try_cast and the procedure is working again, so no time preasure for me.
BUT
I want to understand what happens here, because otherwise I think my brain will explode.

Some sample information:
I try to give you a smaller test SQL Statement because the BI Statement is relativ big.
So the SELECT INTO Statement in the procedure looks something like this:
SELECT  cast(isnull(t1.IstGesamt / nullif(t1.SollGesamt, 0) - 1, 0) as decimal(12,3)) as AbwGesamt
    INTO    [dwh_global].[FaktAuftragszeit]
    FROM (
        SELECT  (a.ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT*a.AUFTRAGSMENGE) + a.RUESTZEIT as SollGesamt,
                a.BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST as IstGesamt
        FROM         [ods_am].a
                join [ods_am].b ON (...)                
        WHERE b.auftragsart <> 'WAR'    
         ) t1

The valuetypes are:

a.ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT ->      numeric(8,3)
a.AUFTRAGSMENGE ->        numeric(10,3)
a.RUESTZEIT ->            numeric(8,3)
a.BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST -> numeric(11,3)

The maximum value I get when I change the CAST to TRY_CAST is 450948999.000 (and no NULL Values). So this should be the maximum value and I think I should be able to cast 450948999.000 to decimal(12,3), correct?

Is here maybe someone which knows what this can be and point me to the correct direction? Do I have forgoten something to analyse?
As I mention I found a workaround but I want to understand this issue.
Thank you in advance!

UPDATE (Add Execution Plan):
Plan for SELECT INTO

Plan for SELECT

Looks kind of similar expect the parallelism steps. The selected step is the one which filters the Auftragsart.
WHERE b.auftragsart <> 'WAR'

UPDATE (Add Execution Plan as XML)
Here we have the Execution Plans as XML uploaded to Paste the Plan.
First the one for the SELECT.
Paste the Plan - Select
And the second one is the one for the SELECT INTO.
Paste the Plan - Select Into

Please post the execution plans of both when you use the INTO and when you don't use it. Likely the filter on WHERE b.auftragsart <> 'WAR' is being applied later in the plan for the INTO query, than you expect, or something similar, resulting in larger values being casted before those rows are filtered out.

Hi! I updated my post (hope this is how it is done here). Also let me say thank you for your response (I am glad someone is willing to help me with this).

It's best to share execution plans using Paste The Plan instead of images so that important details like predicate filters are available. Upload the plan XML and add the links to your question.

@Bado For sure, no problem! There's plenty of experts on here happy to help! (I'm not one of them, not because I'm unhappy, rather because I'm not smart enough to be an expert, but I'll do my best to help. :). We just usually require some things from you to help us help you. The execution plan is typically important, and in XML form, like Dan pointed out, would be ideal.

Hi, yes of course this makes totaly sense. I have uploaded both plans as XML to "Paste the Plan".

@Bado try to comment WHERE b.auftragsart <> 'WAR'  and check for new max value. I had similar issue when my query had a filter where status <> 12 and the values with that status had 8 characters, my INSERT failed with "strig value would be truncated" even there was no value with > 8 characters. BUT when commented status <> 12, I received values 12 characters long. It estimated the risult length WITHOUT applying my filter, so I first inserted in temp table and from it into my destination table

I think the reason you're only seeing a maximum of 450948999.000 is because TRY_CAST is hiding overflow values with NULLs.
With the stated datatypes and that calculation, it's quite possible to create overflows using some test data. For example:-
DECLARE @ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT      NUMERIC(8, 3) ;
DECLARE @AUFTRAGSMENGE        NUMERIC(10,3) ;
DECLARE @RUESTZEIT            NUMERIC(8, 3) ;
DECLARE @BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST NUMERIC(11, 3) ;

SET @ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT      = 0.001 ;
SET @AUFTRAGSMENGE        = 0.999 ;
SET @RUESTZEIT            = 0.001 ;
SET @BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST = 99999999.999 ;

SELECT 
   @ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT      AS ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT, 
   @AUFTRAGSMENGE        AS AUFTRAGSMENGE, 
   @RUESTZEIT            AS RUESTZEIT, 
   @BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST AS BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IS,
   (@ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT * @AUFTRAGSMENGE) + @RUESTZEIT AS SollGesamt,
   @BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST as IstGesamt,
   ISNULL(@BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST / NULLIF((@ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT * @AUFTRAGSMENGE) + @RUESTZEIT, 0) - 1, 0) AS AbwGesamt ;

The result (50025012504.752876438219109554777388) can't be CAST as NUMERIC(12, 3) because the allowable range is ±999999999.999.
With test data, I was able to generate a range of results which would cause overflows as low as -99999999999001, and as high as 99999999998999.
I would look into the range of values in the source data columns and determine which combinations of values can result in overflows based on the calculation. You could try a query like this to identify 'bad' data:-
--
;
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT 
      ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT, 
      AUFTRAGSMENGE, 
      RUESTZEIT, 
      BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST,
      ISNULL(BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST / NULLIF((ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT * AUFTRAGSMENGE) + RUESTZEIT, 0) - 1, 0) AS AbwGesamt
   FROM 
      [ods_am] )
SELECT 
   ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT, 
   AUFTRAGSMENGE, 
   RUESTZEIT, 
   BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST,
   AbwGesamt
FROM 
   CTE
WHERE 
   AbwGesamt IS NOT NULL 
   AND TRY_CAST(AbwGesamt AS NUMERIC(12, 3)) IS NULL    
ORDER BY 
   AbwGesamt,
   ZEIT_JE_EINHEIT, 
   AUFTRAGSMENGE,
   RUESTZEIT, 
   BEARBEITUNGSZEIT_IST ;


Hi, and thank you for your help. I know TRY_CAST can create NULL values when there is an overflow, but in the result there are no NULL values. So when TRY_CAST only creates NULL values when the conversation can not happen (however) why is TRY_CAST not creating NULL values while CAST create the exception?
